# Does CS6 have a feature to extract an object from a background using stereography?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, background-removal

I recall reading an article prior to CS6 releasing that Photoshop (or perhaps another CS6 product?) would include a feature that would allow taking a stereographic photo of an object, and then detect the foreground object from the background, thus allowing clean extraction of a photographed object from the background.

I don't own CS6 yet, but I can't for the life of me find this article again. Does this feature exist in CS6, and if so, what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that isn't in CS6 (or CC as far as I can tell). If you're on a PC [here](http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/p/software.html) are a few utilities for making depth maps from stereographic pairs though. Those may give you a starting point at least.

Comment: so crazy, I remember seeing a video of this in action as part of the upcoming adobe release... I guess it got dropped? ;/

Answer (score 0):

You might be recalling the new features in the content aware move tool that was implemented in Photoshop CS6. This is a video explaining the process.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK3aey1U3OA

Answer (score -1):

[image: Refine Edges in Photoshop CS 6]

Its called Refine Edge. Once you have made selection, click this button and drag your brush over the edges of the object. And see the magic :)

Comment: Can you share some extra screenshots showing how would you extract an object from the background as described in the question?